# Activity disappear when press Home Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    startActivity(intent);

}
```

}

this is my main luncher activity (MainActivity)
i am trying to start new activity called Main. so far so good
the application load successfully but when i press the Home btn and return to desktop the application closed without any error and i cant return to it. also when i see the background apps my app isnt there

Comment: "i cant return to it" How are you trying to return to it?

Comment: i click on the backgroundApp button . and i see "No Recent apps"

Answer (score 0):

Check for developer settings in your emulator/phone if your "Don't Keep Activities" checkbox is on or not. Settings > Developer Options - Apps Section at the bottom. If it is checked, make it unchecked. Your explanation is not enough to solve this problem.